# Print Complex Structures with GDB

Tags: c, gdb, structure

Please consider the following structures:

```
/* Complex Structure */
typedef struct
{
char_t  s4_1 [15];
int_t   s4_2;
} struct4_st;

typedef struct
{
char_t  s3_1 [15];
int_t s3_2;
} struct3_st;

typedef struct
{
struct3_st  s2_1;
struct4_st  s2_2;
} struct2_st;


typedef struct
{
int_t   s1_1;
char_t  s1_2;
struct2_st s1_3;
} struct1_st;

struct sample
{
    int_t sample1;
    int_t sample2;
char_t sample3[20];
struct1_st sample4;
} test;
```

If I put a Break-point on the function containing this structure, I can print the parameters of this Structure in Pretty-Print Format.

My Requirement is:

I want to use GDB Output to Write Code to Fill these Structures.

Is there any advanced command which gives Each Struct Member On a Seperate Line, like:

```
gdb$ <command> test
```

Required Output:

```
test.sample1=1
test.sample2=2;
test.sample3="hello"
test.sample4.s1_1=3
test.sample4.s1_2='t'
```

Thanks.

Comment: `set print pretty on`

Comment: 'set print pretty' gives a different display. I want dotted notation in output

Comment: I believe you can write your own C function `void dumpSample(test *myStruct);` which prints as you wish, and call it from gdb: gdb$ print dumpSample(&test)

Comment: I wanted to save that effort. My code is too big, if I could get struct dump from some tool, it would save a lot of effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in command in gdb to do that.

If your gdb is Python-enabled, then it isn't too hard to write it yourself.